# add multiple datatype using collection in c#

Tags: oop, c#-4.0

In one of the interview question i asked below question,i would like to ask you the same as  i failed to answer and still not getting clear idea on it
here is the code

```
public class Bike
{
    public Bike() { }

    public virtual string GetBikedetails()
    {
        return "This is General Bike";
    }
}

public class Honda : Bike
{
    public Honda() { }

    public override string GetBikedetails()
    {
        return "This is Honda Bike";
    }
}

public class Hero : Bike
{
    public Hero() { }

    public override string GetBikedetails()
    {
        return "This is Hero Bike";
    }
}
```

Now following question was asked with reference to above code
1.Make three instance of the class present
2.add them in a collection
3.iterate in a collection to get the object individually

Please respond with your answer.

Comment: You can make Bike as interface.

Comment: no based on above code i have to respond and not by changing the code given

Comment: @NMK can you elaborate more

Comment: I mean to have a IBike instead of Bike as a base class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already everything in place. Need only to create a List of Bike and add the elements of the specific derived type.

```
List<Bike> myList = new List<Bike>();
Bike b = new Bike();
Honda h = new Honda();
Hero r = new Hero();
myList.Add(b);
myList.Add(h);
myList.Add(r);

foreach(var x in myList)
    Console.WriteLine(x.GetBikedetails());
```

Comment: i explained the same as you mentioned but interviewer is expecting some generic collection(without foreach loop is it possible)

Comment: Generic is  term a bit vague. Do you mean a collection where you can insert any kind of elements with nothing in common? (just for example a bike and a fish?)

Comment: they got something in common with base and sub class relation,in that context i am asking

Comment: I fail to see where this code doesn't answer to three question asked: 1) Make 3 instances... done, 2)Add them in a collection...done, 3) Iterate the collection to get.... done. I think you have done well, but the interviewer being the interviewer shouldn't explain after dismissal of the proposed solution, so... let's see if someone else could find a better answer.